# What is the "virtual execution stack"?

Tags: .net, stack

I am reading about CIL and I keep seeing reference to a "virtual execution stack" (for instance when creating local variables and assigning values to them).

But I don't understand what the virtual execution stack is, exactly. Is it the "call stack", the same stack that we always refer to when we say that structs are loaded on the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack instruction sets are directly executed in the hardware. On the other hand, virtual stack instructions are interpreted in software. Being virtual is on the same line as it is with VM (virtual machines) where you would get an emulated operation system inside of a VM. In virtual stack, all the hardware stack is abstracted (isolated) away from you.

For instance machine language (010001) is directly processed by the hardware (CPU). Virtual instructions on the other hand are processed by the software, emulating and isolating the complicated behavior of underlying hardware. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine#Virtual_stack_machines

Read some about "Java Virtual Machine" which is probably the most popular implementation of virtual stack machines.

Comment: @Teoman: Ok, thanks. And when talking about CIL, is the virtual execution stack the same as the call stack that is always talked about in .NET? There is only this one stack? I just wonder if they are two names for the same thing?

Comment: @Teoman: Ok cool, thank you. So you are saying there is only one "stack", the "call stack", the "virtual executioni stack". And then there is also a heap, which is entirely different. Correct?

Comment: "stack", "heap" = memory zones where data is stored. "call stack" = memory map where methods are lined up to modify stack or heap allocated memory. I know a bit confusing at first:) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29

Comment: LOL OK! I get it. There is a call stack, which is the memory map for methods are lined up for modifying "memory zones". Then there are two "memory zones" - the "stack" (also called the "virtual execution stack"), and the heap. Correct?

Comment: @Teoman: LMAO Ok. 1 stack. It serves for both the memory map and the local variables. Correct?? Those wikipedia articles helped. I see that the stack stores the memory address for where to return to when the method is finished, and pushes local values on top of that. Then when the method finishes the locals are popped off and the memory address returns the execution back to the calling method.